# Restrict access to the AWS ALB only to the NLB

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-elb

We have created a few REST services on EC2 and exposing them through `API Gateway Rest API - Public` as shown below.

API Gateway --(via VPC PrivateLink)--> NLB -> ALB -> EC2

We would like to make sure that NLB is the only one accessing the ALB, but NLB doesn't have Security Group.

How do restrict to make sure NLB is the only accessing the ALB and no one else?

Answer (score 2):

You can put your NLB in a seperate private subnet and set the ALB to only allow from that subnet's CIDR

Comment: The solutions works. But, there are a few cons

1. Requires a separate subnet
2. Each of these subnets will have 5 reserved IP addresses

I was looking for some IP address associated with the VPC Link.

Comment: 1. Yes, but you can use the smallest CIDR so that we can save the private IPs 2. According to this blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/understanding-vpc-links-in-amazon-api-gateway-private-integrations/, when you create the VPC links, you will also create a network interface. You can find it